# How can I select a older version of ubuntu ie 12.04 in aws ec2 instance.when I launch the instance I can only see ubuntu 14.x

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudera-manager

I need ubuntu 12.04 for my cloudera manager to install.It can't be installed on 14.04.So how can I choose the older version of ubuntu in mt ec2 instance?

Answer (score 7):

Go to: [Ubuntu AMI Finder](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/)

Scroll All the way to bottom of the page. Select version as `12.04`. Select region and it will return a list of AMIs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**This version of Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS is not available to new customers.**

So you need to see the compatibility for your required software under 14.04. Check the support forums since people would have surely moved on.